# How to put error bar ahead barplot & change order of bars?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, errorbar

I'm making a bar plot with ggplot and I would know how to change a few details.
First, like you can see on the figure [image: barplot] my error bars are placed behind my bars, and I would like to put them ahead.
Second, I'd like to set aside bars of the same color (for example, light blue, dark blue, light orange, dark orange), but I don't know how.

Here is my code :

```
barplotG=ggplot(donnees_tot_g_J4, aes(x=as.factor(quantity), y=meang, ymin=meang-sd, ymax=meang+sd, fill=color))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",  position = position_dodge())+
  geom_errorbar(stat="identity", position = position_dodge())+
  geom_col(aes(color = color, fill = color),  position = position_dodge()) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("20S" = "aquamarine2","28S" = "aquamarine4","20Y" = "darkgoldenrod1", "28Y" = "darkgoldenrod4"))+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("20S" = "aquamarine2","28S" = "aquamarine4","20Y" = "darkgoldenrod1", "28Y" = "darkgoldenrod4"))+
  ggtitle("Taux de croissance à J4 en fonction du traitement de nourriture et de la température")+
  xlab("Quantité nutritionnelle") + ylab("Taux de croisssance (µg/j)")+
  theme_grey(base_size = 22)
barplotG
```

Comment: The plot elements are drawn in the order you call them. You are calling `geom_col` after `geom_errorbar`. Simply move it to be before `geom_errorbar`. Your call to `geom_bar` doesn't do anything here and can be removed. I don't know what you mean by "set aside" bars of different colors. Set them aside where? Which bars?

Comment: For my bars, I want to make bars of the same color range next to each other for each values of my x axis. For example, for my quantity 0.1 of my x axis, I'd like to have my bars in this order : light blue, dark blue, light orange, dark orange. And I would like that for each values of my x axis

Comment: You should be able to specify the order using `breaks` inside `scale_fill_manual`

Comment: I just try to use `breaks` inside `scale_fill_manual` but it didn't work..

Comment: You can try making `color` a factor and putting the levels of the factor in the order you want the bars to appear

Comment: I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do but I will searched how to do that. Thank you Allan

Comment: To group the bars by color, the easiest thing might be to add the line `facet_wrap(~color)`.